# Best farming place to get ready for Inferno

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

Recently I've unlocked Inferno and I was uber happy. Until I encountered first group of elites. Now I'm at `A1Q3` when I have to go out of the New Tristram from the north exit. And there are always groups of elites that kill me about 7-10 times before I can kill all of them. So I decided to farm a bit in Hell.

Right now I'm farming Zoltan Kulle and Belial(getting lvl 5 `Nephalem Valor` before encountering them ofc.), but the items seem to be too weak for Inferno. So the question is: where should I farm items to be ready for Inferno? And I don't think I can kill Hell Diablo myself yet.

Comment: FWIW, Blizzard is planning on addressing this in 1.0.3 ([blog post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6262208/Patch_103_Design_Preview-6_6_2012))  Reading this seems to indicate that playing A4 Hell or A1 Inferno would (or will?) be your best bets.   The way they explain it, it seems like for the time being, you have to farm the act you're having trouble with to get the gear you need to stop having trouble with it.

Comment: I disagree with merging the other question into this - my answer is out of place here, it addresses **where** to farm and not **what** to do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can't kill Hell Diablo yourself yet, then you certainly aren't ready for Inferno yet. As to where to farm, currently it's a little weird. Act 3/4 Hell is where you should be, but currently the level 60 gear doesn't drop until you are actually inside Inferno. I believe the best gear you can get in Hell is level 59, so aim for all level 55+ gear. If you're still needing gear, then the AH may be a good option. Currently you really need to be farming Act 1 Inferno to get gear to be able to complete Act 1 Inferno, which is kind of frustrating.

As of 1.0.3 release, [level 60 gear will start dropping in Act 3/4 Hell](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6262208/Patch_103_Design_Preview-6_6_2012) as well as [the Hellish Whimsy-shire](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/uoooj/i_am_we_are_wyatt_cheng_andrew_chambers_and_jay/c4x7elj). This should make farming to get into Inferno a little easier.

If it makes you feel any better, my Monk is in all level 60 gear from the AH and still struggling to make it to Leoric. It's a little ridiculous at the moment.

Comment: I disagree with the ridiculous statement, with a little investment (<50k per piece of armor) from the AH you should be able to handle act 1 inferno without any issues.

Comment: @yx. There's a good chance there's an element of "I just suck" in that last paragraph, though I'm pretty sure I just made some bad gear choices when buying up stuff (I managed to just about erase all my +vit) and haven't had the money or inclination to fix it yet. Though, I still do alright for the first 5-6 quests due to very high armour/resists. Still need more meat in my meat shield though.

Comment: I  would highly recommend investing in a relatively cheap 500+ life on hit weapon.  You can pick up a decent one(400-500dps) if you get lucky for <50k

Answer (score 12):

The short answer is that it will depend a lot on your skill & equipment; if you're the god of kiting and never get hit - then all you need is enough dps to kill elites before they enrage, and you can stroll into Inferno asap.

### Gear Checks

- **Good DPS**: You can start Act 1 with 10k dps for tank melee classes; but there is some lower bound as elites will now enrage after 2 mins. You could get around elite enrage by zoning etc., but you need to raise the damage output for boss enrage anyway.
- **Movement Speed**: Even the white mobs get a speed boost in Inferno, esp. for kiting classes you absolutely want to be faster/or atleast same speed as them.
- **All Resistance**: Make sure you get 100+ as a melee class (to start with). For ranged, not really important at first; but pick up AllRes where you can without sacrificing dps.
- **Vitality**: Decent lvl 60 gear with mainstat/vit and no AllRes is quite cheap. For new 60s, keep a lookout for cheap deals to boost VIT so you can take a hit or two.
- **Life on Hit/Life Leech**: If you have relied more on life leech in earlier difficulties, note that its efficiency greatly decreases in Inferno. As such, you may want to focus more on LoH (life on hit).

### Skill Checks

- **Know elite affixes**: If you are the type to shoot first and figure out it was Reflect Damage later - you will face more repair bills with a higher dps. Learn the various affixes and how to deal with them.
- **Resource Management**: Keeping an eye on your CDs (cooldowns) and the res to cast them becomes very important. e.g. DH trying to SS with no discipline -> esp. if you use Sentry, then you need to be careful not to spam it.
- **Spatial awareness**: Learning to dodge back from arcane beams; move immediately when desecrate is cast under you etc. This you should have already learnt in Hell mode.
- **CC breaker**: Getting jailed over an area effect will be near-instant death without extremely good gear - don't hunt without CC breaking and/or escape skills in your list.

In general, your consideration for moving into Inferno is simple: *do you die often enough to make a loss on your repairs*? If so, then move back to Hell and farm there to improve your equip & skills. If not, there is still a tradeoff as you can farm faster in Hell than Inferno - so you may want to have a good set of GF gear to occasionally run through A3 Hell for income, even as you continue progress through Inferno.

Comment: My answer is a general explanation, but to address your specific question: yes, go right into Inferno and see if you can handle it (repair costs will let you know that!)

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need a good weapon from the AH for about 10-50 k and some good gear from Hell. Depending on your class you just need to farm good 57 gear, because as Deamonhunter or as Wizard (damge dealer or DD) it is completely normal to get oneshot at least in Act 2 and above, so just adjust your playing style.

As DD your main goal is to increase your DPS until you can kill Skeletons etc. with 1 to two shots. As tank you need to boost your defense until you can survive melee combat against normal monsters.

You cannot kill every Elite in Inferno, as there are very very nasty combinations. Mages struggle with Reflect Damage especially in combination with Increased Health. So if there is an "unbeatable" Elite either restart, avoid him and try to get your buff somewhere else or skip him by running him into a distant corner and dying.

If you are unable to do the above ask in the chat if someone can help you with one or two Leoric runs. Currently many people are stuck with act 1 as you need really good gear for everything above.

If you have friends that are level 60 already, just ask them for some items or if you can join on some Leoric runs. Usually a good level 60 damage dealer can easily output the required DPS.

If you are a tank and no one is willing to tag you along then ask in general chat for cheap gear. Many people, me included, have a ton of decent items that they cannot sell in the AH because of inflation and limited auctions. If you are willing to buy for 6-7 times the vendor price people will sell you cheap stuff so you can at least start Leoric runs yourself.

As already stated you could also wait for the patch that reduces the gap between Hell and Inferno.

Answer (score 0):

Too be honest a gold find set and doing the Royal crypts to get some cash may be even better. A lot of Act 3 gear+ is hitting the market and everything is trending downwards.

Comment: The jars in the Royal crypts aren't a good spot any more, see by yourself this [blue post](http://www.diablofans.com/blizz-tracker/topic/226376-diablo-iii-hotfixes-june/)

Answer (score 0):

You should farm Hell until you have your gear ready to survive Inferno. Most importantly you need a good weapon. You should look for something with high DPS with a socket.

It is all right to invest all your money in your weapon, as you can actually farm your armor and you will kill stuff way faster in Hell.

I would just try to start Inferno and if you see you get killed way too often then go back to Hell. Your main goal is to reach the Cemetery as there you can get 3-6 champions. You get another 3-6 in the Cathedral.

With the current patch the best way to go is to kill champions and hope they drop good stuff. I would not recommend farming Leoric, as he got buffed.

Here is a priority list especially for Demon Hunters:

- Go glass cannon first: Maximum DPS while sacrificing defense. You might get 1 shot. Your goal is to kill "some" champions.
- Once you reach a "comfortable level" with your DPS, thats about 18k+ w/o SS, try to change your gear with something more resilient. The goal is to die less often.
- If you are lucky and drop some good MF gear use it, but do not try to use crappy MF gear as you will die more often while swapping.

My personal opinion is that a Demon Hunter cannot effectively farm Act 2 and/or 3 without a group or really good gear. It is not worth kiting 1 champion for 10 minutes or getting oneshot from monsters that charge you all the time.

Comment: Since this question has been merged with it's duplicate, you might want to consider combining your two answers and deleting one. (In the future, you might *also* consider voting to close duplicate questions like this rather than rewriting answers to them!)