# How to farm as an early lvl 60 in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best farming place to get ready for Inferno](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72913/best-farming-place-to-get-ready-for-inferno)

I'll be hitting 60 when ending Hell, and I'm wondering what I should do next? Farm Hell again and again or directly run into Inferno?

How can I tell when I'm ready to move on to Inferno from Hell on my Demon Hunter?